# require('electron').app is undefined - how to solve this

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, electron

I'm using cordova and i'm trying to add a screenshot-functionality in electron.
The screenshot itself works really fine. I'm using for it the desktopCapturer from electron.

`const {desktopCapturer} = required('electron');`

So i know, that i can access on the node-module from electron, also nodeIntegration is enabled. But if i try to get the app or dialog module, it tells me, that these are undefined.

`const {app, dialog, desktopCapturer} = required('electron');`

Do you know if Cordova remove these modules from electron or how to access these?

Maybe it's a problem with the electron-location.
The output from `require.resolve('electron')` is `APPLOCATION/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar.rederer/api/exports/electron.js`

Known Packages with versions:

```
"cordova-electron": "^1.1.0",
"electron": "^4.0.1"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To access `app` from the renderer process, you need to get it through `remote`.

So instead of :

```
const {app} = require('electron');
```

Use

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
const {app} = remote; // or `const app = remote.app`
```

Comment: Thanks!
Was easier than i thought...

Found it in the exakt some moment here:
https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/212