# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Tags: javascript, electron

after update my project electron (19) will not start.

i got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whenReady')
```

i tried already change "whenReady" to app.on("ready",...) but same error with "undefined (reading 'on')"

Tried to install electron directly in the dist folder.. but still same.

My electron main.js is in the angular folder "src/electron"... Maybe he has here a Problem?

```
// const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
// const electron = require('electron');
// const app = require('app');
// const BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')

function createWindow() {
  // Erstelle das Browser-Fenster.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    },
  });

  // und lade die index.html der App.
  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {createWindow()});
// app.on('ready',createWindow);
```

EDIT:
when i try

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('./node_modules/electron');
```

instead of

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
```

the errormessage is still the same, but not in console of electron anymore but in console of terminal (node)

[image]

````
{
  "name": "aurin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open | node src/Backend/api.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-electron": "ng build --base-href . && cp src/electron/* dist/",
    "electron": "npm run build-electron && ./node_modules/.bin/electron --no-sandbox dist/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.10",
    "@coreui/angular": "^4.0.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^6.7.96",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "cron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron": "^17.4.7",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "luxon": "^2.4.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.7.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql-event-emitter": "^1.0.8",
    "mysql-events": "0.0.11",
    "ng-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-toastr": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.3.0",
    "node-schedule": "^2.1.0",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^13.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "save": "^2.5.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~17.0.36",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.8.0",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```
````

Comment: The starter project uses `whenReady()` yours looks right https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js#L25 maybe running `npm ci` will fix it.

Comment: Make sure you've actually installed electron. Also, make sure that you are passing the `main` property in the package.json

Comment: npm ci, doesn't help. Also electron downgrade to 17 not help.
electron is installed, also in the /dist folder, package.json has main property...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require('electron').app is undefined - how to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164188/requireelectron-app-is-undefined-how-to-solve-this)

Comment: no... same same error

Comment: so you only started seeing this after updating Electron? What does your package.json look like?

Comment: see my last edit...